# TabLayout transition state

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I want to have a tablayout, in which the current tab would have a purple background and white text while the unselected would have white background and purple background. It is pretty simple to implement using a linear layout and textviews, and setting their background when onPageSelect is called.

I was looking for a way to shift the background when the viewpager is moving. Like this
[image: my current layout]

 For this I have two linearlayouts, one containing the tabs and one the background.I was moving the background using a empty view using a onPageChangeListener(). But I am not able to change the textColor in between the transition states.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector in drawable.Selector look like the below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/your color" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/your color"/>
</selector
```

and add selector to the background of_tablayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/circular_progress_default_progress"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector_color"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

Comment: This would just change the background color of tab when it is selected or not. I want to change the textcolor of the tab when the indicator is between two states. Please correct me if I am wrong in understanding what your code does.